# How to render an image to a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, renderer

I want to apply a renderer on a cell of my JTable, to do so I created a class named myRenderer :

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, ImageIcon icon) {

setIcon(icon);
return this;
}
}
```

And I use this piece of code to apply the renderer on the cell :

```
MyRenderer renderer = new MyRenderer();

renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, icon);

table.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

The problem is that the rebderer is applied on all the cells in the column 6, and I want it to be applied on one cell only (row/column) but I don't know how to do so ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the fact that you are not even properly overriding the `getTableCellRendererComponent` method, you don't even need a custom renderer to display an image in a column

From [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). Here's a list of types with default pre-configured renderers

- `Boolean` — rendered with a check box.
- `Number` — rendered by a right-aligned label.
- `Double, Float` — same as Number, but the object-to-text translation is performed by a NumberFormat instance (using the default number format for the current locale).
- `Date` — rendered by a label, with the object-to-text translation performed by a DateFormat instance (using a short style for the date and time).
- `ImageIcon`, Icon — rendered by a centered label.
- `Object` — rendered by a label that displays the object's string value.

So you can put add an `ImageIcon` to the table and it will be rendered as such, given you properly override the `getColumnClass()`

Also from tutorial:

> To choose the renderer that displays the cells in a column, a table first determines whether you specified a renderer for that particular column. If you did not, then the table invokes the table model's `getColumnClass` method, which gets the data type of the column's cells. Next, the table compares the column's data type with a list of data types for which cell renderers are registered

So say you have a `DefaultTableModel` with three columns and you want an `ImageIcon` in the last column. You would do something like this

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(...) {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 2: return ImageIcon.class;
            default: return String.class
        }
    }
};
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Then by just adding an `ImageIcon` to the third column, it will be rendered as such

```
String colOneDate = "Data";
String colTwoData = "Data";
ImageIcon colThreeIcon = new ImageIcon(...);
model.addRow(new Object[] { colOneData, colTwoData, colThreeIcon });
```

You will probably also want to set the column widths and height accordingly, to the size of the image. For that you can see any of [these questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20set%20column%20with%20and%20height%20of%20jtable#q=site%3astackoverflow.com+how+to+set+column+width+and+height+of+jtable&spell=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use getTableCellRendererComponent function in as described below. The icon, row and coulmn to display icon, you can set from out side using a setter methode

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;


  public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

public MyRenderer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
            row, column);

    int neededRow=0; // set the needed row here in which the icon to be dispayed
    int neededcolumn=0; // set the needed column here in which the icon to be dispayed

    if(row==neededRow && column==neededcolumn)
    {
        setIcon(icon);
    }

    return this
}
}
```